# Product Catalog images cannot be indexed

Tags: magento2, seo, index, gallery

In Magento 2, I site: my site in google images, and I found that all the large images didn't be indexed by google, I checked the code in product catalog page, all these images in gallery was shown like

> https://www.mysite.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/thumbnail/88x110/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/2/0/3291/2472/sans-manches-tulle-printemps-robe-de-soiree-demoiselle-d-honneur-turquoise-gland-empire-decollete.jpg

looks that makes google doesn't indexed it, how to make google index all of my products images?

Comment: images in gallery was shown like 
 https:\/\/www.ricici.com\/pub\/media\/catalog\/product\/cache\/thumbnail\/88x110\/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582\/2\/0\/251\/3098\/herrlich-glitzernden-mit-pailletten-glanz-schleife-gold-kurzarm-sommer-tull-konfirmations-weihnachts-cocktail-festliche-kleider-etui.jpg